# htaccess 301 redirect rule for multiple query strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I just want 301 redirect rule for multiple query string to make it SEO friendly url.

Internal Url: `www.example.com?p=54&p1=ABC XYZ&p2=XXX45767` and so on.

301 Redirect Url: `www.example.com/54-ABC-XYZ-XXX45767?p=54&p1=ABC XYZ&p2=XXX45767`

So, the redirect url must contain the old query parameters too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to check the `QUERY_STRING` for the parameters in question. If a match is found, then a redirect should occur.

You can use the following in your `/.htaccess` file:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On

# Check the query string and capture parts
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]+)&p1=([^&]+)&p2=([^&]+)$

# If at the root of the domain, redirect
RewriteRule ^$ /%1-%2-%3 [R=302,L]
```

To make the redirect permanent and cached by browsers and search engines, change `302` to `301`.